# Jar file in package is not a file or directory

Tags: java, jar

I put a Jar File in my package, and then did this:

```
File sourceFileOrDir = new File("/javaproject/src/package/CoFHCore-[1.7.10]3.1.4-329.jar");
    System.out.println(sourceFileOrDir.isDirectory());
    System.out.println(sourceFileOrDir.isFile());
```

To copy the .jar file to another location it has to be a file or directory. The output said it's none of both, but why? I declared a file with the path of the jar, shouldn't it be ok?

Comment: see what returns `sourceFileOrDir.exists()`

Comment: it returns false, too but i put it into the package with this pathname

Comment: What do you see from the shell if you execute `ls -l /javaproject/src/package/CoFHCore-[1.7.10]3.1.4-329.jar`

Comment: A path starting with `/` is an absolute path, meaning there would need to be a `javaproject` directory in the root of your file system.  I’m guessing you meant to write `new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "javaproject/src/package/CoFHCore-[1.7.10]3.1.4-329.jar")`.

Comment: using the `File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "javaproject/src/package/CoFHCore-[1.7.10]3.1.4-329.jar")`  doesn't change the output, still all false

Comment: and my Local Command Shell Console doesn't take the command ls, guess maybe because i'm using windows